# How can I show multi-line Rust error messages in vim?

Tags: vim, compiler-errors, rust

I use Syntastic and the error messages in vim usually only have one line, I find this information to be insufficient.

Is there a compiler flag so the first line of the error is more meaningful, or so that I can see multiline errors in the quickfix window?
I'm having to constantly go and `cargo build` the errors somewhere, which should be just a "put mouse in cursor" away, usually the error fits the space (I have a wide monitor).

I'm using macOS.

Comment: sometimes I get frustrated and lean over my VSCode friends...

Answer (score 3):

`quickfix` windows (actually, `loclist` windows in the case of syntastic) don't support multiline error messages.  This is a limitation of Vim.

What you can do is convince the checker to merge multiline error messages to single lines before parsing them.  Syntastic provides hooks for doing that, but `cargo` is not a standard syntastic checker.  So perhaps [contact](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim/issues) the authors of said checker and post a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

you need correctly setting the Syntastic and rust bundle in vim.
see example in my vimrc(use Vundle):

```
" vimrc
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
Plugin 'racer-rust/vim-racer'
Plugin 'timonv/vim-cargo'

" Syntastic
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = 'EE'
let g:syntastic_style_error_symbol = 'E>'
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = 'WW'
let g:syntastic_style_warning_symbol = 'W>'

let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_rust_checkers = ['cargo']
```

Comment: Please include more details in your answer than a link to a repository. In this instance, your `.vimrc` is 352 lines long, so including the relevant section in your answer would save a lot of effort for people looking for an answer.

Comment: It looks like this snippet turns on Syntastic for Rust, but I don't see how it helps with the original question of including the whole multi-line message?

Answer (score -1):

Do you use `:copen`?  That's the standard way in vim to open a window with the compiler error messages.  `C-w C-w` toggles the cursor between windows.  `:cnext` (or just `:cn`) jumps to the next error message.

Comment: I think syntastic opens the :copen error list automatically when I write the code, however, the error messages which have a type mismatch, usually take more than one line.

Comment: As far I can see Syntastic puts the errors in the "location list" (opened by `:lopen`) not the error list (opened by `:copen`), so this is irrelevant.